# Display the Android WebView's favicon

Tags: android, favicon

I'd like to display the favicon of the website I am accessing via the android.webkit.WebView.  I've tried two ways to get it:

1) `WebViewClient.onPageStarted()` method has a favicon parameter that is always null.

2) `WebChromeClient.onReceivedIcon()` method is never called.

3) Called `WebView.getFavicon()` in `onPageStarted()` and `onPageFinished()` but it always returns null.

I haven't been able to find an example online that shows how to access the favicon.  Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @NathanZ - yes, Mark's answer seemed to do the trick.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For the WebView icon methods and listeners to work, you need to first open the WebIconDatabase manually. You would typically do this in the `onCreate()` method of your Activity.

Try adding the following line to `onCreate()`:

```
WebIconDatabase.getInstance().open(getDir("icons", MODE_PRIVATE).getPath());
```

Once you've done this, you should start getting `onReceivedIcon()` callbacks for any WebView in this Activity, and the `getFavicon()` method should also start returning a valid object rather than null whenever icons are available.

Comment: Having the same problem as @tronman.  I tried your suggestion, adding this code to my onCreate() both before and after setContentView().  I never get any onReceivedIcon() callbacks, and WebView.getFavIcon() is always null.  So no dice =(

Comment: Nice. Please just specify that ' These functions require that a WebView be constructed before being invoked and WebView.getIconDatabase() will return a WebIconDatabase object'

Comment: It says that `WebIconDatabase` is deprecated. I think you should add a check, that it should be used only on `JELLY_BEAN_MR2` and below. Can you please answer why `onReceivedIcon` is called with this bitmap, but in everywhere else when I try to get the favIcon, I get null ?

Answer (score 0):

I think to remember that there is a method `getFavicon()` available for the WebView object. here is my stupid question did you try that?

Comment: Yes, I tried that too.  I've added that to my original post to clarify.

Comment: can you give the url of the site you want to get the favicon from? I'll have a look at that tomorrow morning.

Comment: It doesn't matter which site... I can't get access to the favicon for *any* website. I do appreciate your help.

Comment: Indeed, I've been doing some research, even in the source code, no way to find how to retrieve this favicon. Except if your are getting it from the bookmark...

Comment: Well, I guess I'll need to figure something else out. Thanks!