# Android WebView getFavicon() returning null

Tags: java, android, webview, favicon

I'm trying to get the favicon of the loaded page after using

```
    WebView webView = new WebView(getActivity());
    webView.loadUrl("http://" + url);
```

I'm attaching the asynchronous `WebViewClient` to the `WebView` to get the favicon after it loads

```
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
    {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
        {
            String linkTitle = view.getTitle();
            Bitmap favicon = view.getFavicon();

            onLinkUrlFinished(url, linkTitle);
        }
    });
```

The favicon getting back is always null, even for websites such as google/facebook that has favicons for sure.

Another thread says to use `WebIconDatabase` but it's deprecated:
[Display the Android WebView's favicon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462582/display-the-android-webviews-favicon/5346347#5346347)

The API on android site refers to `WebViewClient.onReceivedIcon` which doesnt even exist.http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#getFavicon%28%29

What's going on here?

Comment: What is your min api in `manifest`?

Comment: min = 14, target = 18

Comment: What is the version of the device you are testing on?

Comment: 4.2.1 on galaxy nexus

Comment: There goes my idea. `WebIconDatabase` is still needed pre-JellyBean

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to use `onReceiveIcon()`, you should use `setWebChromeClient`.
This is what I do and it's working for me.

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
            super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
            progressBar.setProgress(newProgress);
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedIcon(WebView view, Bitmap icon) {
            super.onReceivedIcon(view, icon);
            webImage.setImageBitmap(icon);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

WebIconDatabase is deprecated as of API 19. According to the comments in the code:

> @deprecated This class is only required when running on devices up to
>   {@link android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES#JELLY_BEAN_MR2}

So unless you don't want to support API 18 and below, you should still be using WebIconDatabase:

```
WebIconDatabase.getInstance().open(getDir("icons", MODE_PRIVATE).getPath());
```

And then, regardless what API you want to support, you need to specify in a custom WebChromeClient:

```
public class MyCustomWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {

    @Override
    public void onReceivedIcon(WebView view, Bitmap icon) {
        super.onReceivedIcon(view, icon);
        // do whatever with the arguments passed in
    }
}
```

Remember to register your custom WebChromeClient with your WebView:

```
mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new MyCustomWebChromeClient());
```

Answer (score 0):

The key is to open the `WebIconDatabase` so `WebView` has somewhere to put the icons, and override `WebChromeClient.onReceivedIcon`.  For additional information, see [this StackOverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462582/display-the-android-webviews-favicon).

Comment: did you even read the post tho, my problem is that WebIconDatabase is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

I know its an old thread but, for those facing problems getting favicon using webview client.

Kotlin:

```
override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url)
        tabTitle.text = view?.title // read website title
        loadImg(view)  // method to load the favicon
    }

private fun loadImg (view: WebView?){
    // u can directly use tabImage.setBitmap instead of assigning tabImg as val
    val tabImg: ImageView = findViewById(R.id.tabImage) 
    // creating handler object to delay the associated thread a little bit after onPageFinished is called.
    val handler = Handler()
    val runnable = Runnable {
        if(view?.favicon != null) {
            tabImg.setImageResource(0) //remove the default image
            tabImg.setImageBitmap(view?.favicon) // set the favicon
        }
    }
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 200) // delay time 200 ms
}
```

It worked for me, hope it helps new readers, plz up vote if it helps u, so that u can help others!

Best regards

Answer (score -1):

So in the end I didn't end up using the deprecated API, instead I found out that if you put `/favicon.ico` after the domain, it'll give you the `ico` file, which I used in the end to fetch the image. The Uri API will have a `getHost()` method that will give you the host without having to manually parse it

```
 String faviconUrl = Uri.parse(url).getHost() + "/favicon.ico";
```

For google for example the icon url will be www.google.com/favicon.ico

Comment: There's no guarantee this will work. For instance, http://www.theverge.com/favicon.ico returns a 404 (as of this date).

Comment: @ChrisLacy yea I am aware, but there doesn't seem to be a better alternative