# WebView getFavicon returning null

Tags: android, webview

I want to get the favicon associated with a web page loaded in WebView.  The getFavicon() is simple enough (it returns a Bitmap for the favicon).  But getFavicon() always returns null.

It seems the only solution posted on StackOverflow is to use WebClientDatabase, but that class is deprecated.

So, the problem persists.  My question: How does one get the favicon associated with a web page loaded in WebView?

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18794638/android-webview-getfavicon-returning-null

Comment: Oops, I meant to type "WebIconDatabase", but typed "WebClientDatabase".  In any event, WebIconDatabase is deprecated, so it would be nice to have a solution that does *not* rely on that class.

Comment: Pat, you are pointing me to the answer(s) I alluded to in my original post.  WebIconDatabase is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

If your app is targeting < SDK 19, you need to call `WebIconDatabase.open()` to enable favicon downloading. If you are targeting 19 or higher, there's no need to do this.

You should then receive notifications on new favicons via [WebChromeClient.onReceivedIcon](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.html#onReceivedIcon%28android.webkit.WebView,%20android.graphics.Bitmap%29).

Comment: Thanks.  This worked.  At first I didn't like the idea of using a deprecated class (a carry-over from Java/Swing programming).  But, in Android, it seems using a deprecated class is just fine, provided you target the app accordingly.